# Cannot open tor browser - Frustrated

Tags: configuration

I have been reading through the various forums postings about issues with connecting to Tor but still cannot resolve the issue.

I am a basic Tor User and up until 3 days ago had no issues.

I have Norton Internet Security installed and have confirmed Tor as a trusted connection but since an update a few days ago, cannot access Tor.

When I launch "Start Tor Browser" nothing happens. When I check open processes I see Tor and Firebox both running but nothing happens.

Even Firefox seems to be hanging and not connecting. No problems with IE or Chrome.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox and Tor several times. Even tried to run Tor Browser from my external hard drive. Nothing works.

I would appreciate help from the expert users.

Thank you.

Comment: If this is a general problem with Firefox, as the crash report you provided seems to be about, then it's likely nothing at all to do with Tor.

Comment: Have you tried starting Tor Browser without Norton being active? What were the results?